# NullPointerException on Animation

Tags: java, android, animation, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make animation but I see only NullPointerException

LogCat:

```
06-25 12:13:40.474  12959-12959/com.example.admin.p0201_simpleanimation E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.admin.p0201_simpleanimation.MainActivity.onContextItemSelected(MainActivity.java:92)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2566)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:353)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:144)
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:99)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3633)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I just want to animate simple TextView using context menu.
Cause of exception hides here

> textView.startAnimation(anim);

my onContextMenuItemSelected method:

```
 @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Animation anim = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_ALPHA_ID:
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myalpha);
            break;
        case MENU_COMBO_ID:
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mycombo);
            break;
        case MENU_ROTATE_ID:
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myrotate);
            break;
        case MENU_SCALE_ID:
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myscale);
            break;
        case MENU_TRANSLATE_ID:
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans);
            break;
    }
        textView.startAnimation(anim);

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

One of my XML animations files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="3000">
</alpha>`
```

this file is located in

> res/anim/myalpha.xml

Help me please. What's wrong?

Comment: see in your code you setting Animation anim = null;

Comment: Are there any other menu choices not in the switch? That plus anim set to null would do it. Try adding a default case in the switch.

Comment: Any down-voters should post a comment as explanation. This is a new user so cut 'em some slack!!!

Comment: Where is `textView` declared?

Comment: @cb4 on the other hand, new users are supposed to read the rules on how to ask a question ;-) There is little need to 'cut them some slack'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of exception hides here

```
textView.startAnimation(anim);
```

The only way for an NPE here is that `textView` is `null`. Make sure you have initialized it.

Comment: Thank u very much! i realy made a mistake there!

Answer (score 1):

have you initialized the textview ? using `findViewById()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add default for your switch case statement, something like this,

```
      case MENU_TRANSLATE_ID:
       default::
          anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans);
          break;
```

If the id doesn't match to anyone the it could result `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line

```
Animation anim = null;
```

to

```
Animation anim = new Animation();
```